# Adding Data to Table with Foreign Key

Tags: foreign-keys

I am trying to add one row of data into a table (Employee) that has a Foreign Key (ob_Num). Job_Num is referenced in the Job table. However, when I go to add the row I get the below error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Employee__Job_Nu__5D60DB10". The
>   conflict occurred in database "team04", table "dbo.Job", column
>   'Job_Num'. The statement has been terminated.

My code is:

> Insert into Employee Values (001, 'Celie', 'Davis', 457-457-4511, 002,
>   '01-05-2012', null);

002 is the job_num